# Laravel 4 - Read config files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can i read the config files from laravel? For example for the database connection (app/config/database/.php)

I want the mysql data from the config.

For a package you do it like that:

```
return Config::get('package::group.option');
```

But how to do it for the main files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do `Config::get('database.default')` for example.

Comment: TThank you, but got a stupid question. How an i now access the values?

Comment: `default` is a value, so essentially what you'd like is `database.connections.mysql.database` to access the `database` name.

Comment: Do I need to `use` a class or file for this?

Answer (score 6):

To get the database connection parameters (server, username, password etc) if you're using MySQL, you can do this:

```
echo "Driver: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.driver') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Host: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.host') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Database: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Username: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.username') . "<br/>\r\n";
echo "Password: " . Config::get('database.connections.mysql.password') . "<br/>\r\n";
```

On my local development machine this gives:

> Driver: mysql
>
> Host: localhost
>
> Database: local_dev_db
>
> Username: root
>
> Password: not-my-real-pwd

...obviously you should never show your password (or any of these other details) in your live app! But if it's just for your information on a local development machine you should be fine.

If you're not using MySQL, just replace `mysql` with `sqlite` or `pgsql` or whatever.