# How to execute Join queries between multiple Databases that are on different server with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5

This is how we handle multiple DB Connections with Laravel, which is a **PHP Framework** not **Python** (For whom thinks that this is a duplicate post)

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And this is how you connect to this database.

```
$user1 = User::on('mysql1')->where(/* ... */)->get()
$user2 = User::on('mysql2')->where(/* ... */)->get()
```

These are only SELECT queries. Therefore Eloquent works flawlessly.

However, when I want to execute a **JOIN query** operation between these 2 databases, this seems not possible.

Comment: You basically can't (it might be possible with the FEDERATED storage engine but I couldn't vouch for it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL -- Joins Between Databases On Different Servers Using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python)

Comment: @GordonM this is a PHP framework not a Phyton framework and Eloquent. I think Phyton doesn't have Eloquent as well. Therefore, it is impossible to be a duplicate. Don't write something for only purpose of writing.

Comment: The high level language and/or framework aren't relevant.  What is relevant is what the database engine can and can't support.  If the engine supports cross-server joins then it should be possible in both PHP and Python.  If not then it's not possible in either language.

Comment: @SNaRe, Gordon isn't wrong to have said what he said. He possibly should have given more info. The point is that if you think you can do it without Laravel/Eloquent (i.e. command line MySQL or something) *then* it's a potential issue/question in Laravel/Eloquent, but I'm pretty sure a genuine SQL `JOIN` is not possible across servers. Now if you want to know how to merge two Laravel `Collection`s (based on results from two different connections), or potentially see the results of a non-native foreign key relationship (1 table one one server, 1 on another), that's a different matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If these 2 databases are on different servers, you can't do this. At least not simply. I read about a [storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html). But I have never tried to do this before.

**BUT**

If there databases are on the same server, you can do it with a simple join, IF the **user has the right permission**!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not do this using Eloquent ORM or Laravel's query builder.

However, you can try to use raw expression (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8865d2276be94f0a3497ba3bd26c906ae9e91e1c/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Expression.php#L13 ) or smth like this, but you'll have to write code to make a model from query result.

If you use laravel 4 this question can help: [Laravel 4: how to run a raw SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql)

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions I see raw method but when I use it how I will append these 2 database connection names to my raw sql code? I am okay with Raw SQL. I just gotta solve this.

Comment: Smth like this I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132206/laravel-4-read-config-files

Answer (score 0):

Write a raw query and use laravels DB methods to escape data.

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT Users.id, Properties.name FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Users] join [Database2].[dbo].[Properties] on Users.id = Properties.user_id where [so].[dbo].[Users].id = :user_id"), array('user_id' => Input::get('user_id', -1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do mysql joins between different database servers, this is a mysql limitation, not related to laravel or eloquent.

Your best bet is use the 2 different database connections as you already have, then merge and query the data through your php code.